# How to add tags like Author,Title and Thumbnail to an .m4a audio file using node.js?

Tags: node.js, metadata, thumbnails, id3, m4a

Using Node.js to download files containing music, in `.m4a` format.

Issue: I cannot find a way to add tags and the Cover Art (thumbnail) to .m4a files.

I had done this before using another program: achieved by MediaHuman youtube -> mp3 downloader (even though it downloads as m4a, my desired format) https://ufile.io/yzyzt

(P.S.I'm open to use another language, as long as the language can be linked it to node, but it is definitely very much preferred if it could be done purely in node.js)

Any clues on this subject are very appreciated.

Comment: I would execute FFmpeg as a child process to handle this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had no luck to actually get FFmpeg running, I've spent several hours trying to get to actually work, I'm really new to this. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved my issue by the use of ffmpeg using node!

https://www.ffmpeg.org/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

The issue was that \node_modules\ffmpeg\lib\video.js decided to skip duplicate commands, therefore my requests consisting of multiple of same commands were never read properly by ffmpeg. However, with a quick mod to the video.js file, I was able to make it work! I have successfully written both, the tags, and a thumbnail onto my .m4a

Comment: Do you mind to share with us your _video.js_ mod script ?

Comment: Sure! here it is: https://pastebin.com/nMg77nRr
keep in mind, i already integrated it into my program, so there's a few extras, but you'll find the essentials in there ^^

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use [node-taglib2](https://github.com/voltraco/node-taglib2), a Node.js C++ addon based on taglib and available in the npm repository.

This module makes trivial editing mpeg metadata:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const taglib = require('taglib2');

let props = {
  artist: 'Howlin\' Wolf',
  title: 'Evil is goin\' on',
  pictures: [
    {
      "mimetype": 'image/jpeg',
      "picture": fs.readFileSync('./thumbnail.jpg')
    } 
  ]
}

taglib.writeTagsSync('./file.m4a', props);
```

Now we can check that metadata have been updated:

```
let tags = taglib.readTagsSync('./file.m4a')

console.log(tags.artist, '-', tags.title)  // Howlin' Wolf - Evil is goin' on
console.log(tags.pictures)  // [ { mimetype: 'image/jpeg', picture: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03 03 03 03 04 03 03 04 05 08 05 05 04 04 05 0a 07 07 06 ... > } ]
```

But of course there are others options to do the same thing and I'm sure you could also use ffmpeg, as mentioned by Brad in his comment. I would be interested in your feedback if you try it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out first thing tomorrow! looks promising!!

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you without any results, but I'm having issues installing taglib2. I have installed two different versions of Visual Studio with no luck for the taglib2 to install anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure about how to install it on windows. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40525033/5156280) answer can help.

Comment: Hey! I managed to install node-id3, and... Well, either I don't know how to use it specifically for m4a, or... m4a is unsupported. It destroys the audio (completely gone) and "writes" the tags, which only it itself can read. It basically corrupts the file... Trying to continue with ffmpeg now, but i'm having same results with ffmpeg, minus the corruption of file part.