# Is it necessary to install Visual Studio C++ Build Tools if Visual Studio 2017 is already installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, build, visual-studio-2017

`Visual studio 2017 community` is installed on my PC along with `Visual Studio Build Tools 2017`. I am using Windows 10.

Is it still necessary to install `Visual C++ Build Tools`? Is there a possibility that there will be some packages that cannot be compiled if `Visual C++ Build Tools` is not available even though `Visual Studio Build Tools 2017` is there?

Comment: "It didn't fix my problems, though." - if you don't say what those problems were, it's hard to advise. Can you build and execute a simple C++ "hello World" console program?

Comment: Build Tools is intended for systems that do not have the Visual Studio IDE installed.  I believe the IDE comes with the build tools integrated.  You should not require a separate installation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools This might help.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, I edited that comment away to avoid confusing readers with unrelated issues. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Well, no, that doesn't fix the question per my previous comment.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, I missed that question in your comment. No problem building and executing C++ programs with both build tools.