# Trying to install PyCaret

Tags: python-3.x, pycaret

I am trying to install `PyCaret[full]` on a new machine.

within an environment, I got the below error. Doesn't seem to be much information around it!

Here is the packages in the environment:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2022.10.11           haa95532_0
certifi                   2022.9.24        py38haa95532_0
libffi                    3.4.2                hd77b12b_6
openssl                   1.1.1s               h2bbff1b_0
pip                       22.2.2           py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.15               h6244533_2
setuptools                65.6.3                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.40.0               h2bbff1b_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
```

My first error was related to Python package so I installed older version. Now I have the below error:

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
  Downloading Boruta-0.1.4.tar.gz (8.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
  Downloading Boruta-0.1.3.tar.gz (8.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
  Downloading Boruta-0.1.2.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      long_description_markdown_filename: dist = <setuptools.dist.Distribution object at 0x000002627C196B50>; attr = 'long_description_markdown_filename'; value = 'README.md'
      markdown_filename = 'C:\\Users\\HAXY8W\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s6tk4h5o\\boruta_fe771e3ba2bc4fec84264bb9a059531e\\README.md'
      C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:770: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        warnings.warn(
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6tk4h5o\boruta_fe771e3ba2bc4fec84264bb9a059531e\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
          setup(name='Boruta',
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 147, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 475, in __init__
          _Distribution.__init__(
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 283, in __init__
          self.finalize_options()
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 899, in finalize_options
          ep(self)
        File "C:\Users\HAXY8W\.conda\envs\pycaret_py38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 919, in _finalize_setup_keywords
          ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
        File "c:\users\haxy8w\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-s6tk4h5o\boruta_fe771e3ba2bc4fec84264bb9a059531e\.eggs\setuptools_markdown-0.4.1-py3.8.egg\setuptools_markdown.py", line 43, in long_description_markdown_filename
          output = pypandoc.convert(markdown_filename, 'rst', format='md')
      AttributeError: module 'pypandoc' has no attribute 'convert'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a few things here:

(1) The current version of pycaret is 2.3.10. Try not to install the [full] version if possible since it may install lot of libraries that you may not end up using. If you do need a library from [full] install it manually if possible.

(2) You can try the pre-release version of pycaret 3.0.0. This has a lighter footprint and is often easier to install.

```
pip install -U --pre pycaret
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution were able to help close the issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67876218/10299633

also, sometimes `pip install pycaret[full]` doesn't work, try without it and it might just go through