# MS Visual C++ not recognized when installing Python package

Tags: python, visual-c++

### The problem

I am trying to install a Python package called dedupe. It's available with `pip install dedupe`, but get the following error:

```
    Running setup.py install for Levenshtein-search ... error
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    [...]
    Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft 
    C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

But I have MS C++ Build Tools installed (the latest version).

And the strange thing is: I once had a 32bit version of Python 3.8 on my PC, and here, dedupe was installed without problems (but then didn't process my data due to a so called MemoryError – a problem I ascribe to the 32bit version).

### What I tried

- Uninstalled all Python interpreters on the system
- Un- and re-installed MS C++ Build Tools
- Re-installed Python 3.10 64bit
- created a venv-environment with that interpreter
- updated setuptools

But still, the error persists.

I have **looked for similar questions** and tried their solutions:

- [How to install Visual C++ Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools): I have Build Tools installed (Workload "Desktop Development with C++)
- [Installing Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t) doesn't do the job for me, including [the latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057393/17861599). And the weird thing: While I wasn't able to install `misaka`, too (the package discussed in this question), installing `spacy` was not a problem (while some other person had problems with that).

### So?

Does anybody have an idea why my 64bit Python might not recognize Visual C++?