# Can't pip install insightface==0.7.3

Tags: face, insight

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUJRL.png) error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required, but I have C++ 14.0 and Python installed
download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error.

× Building wheel for insight face (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [215 lines of output]
WARNING: pandoc not enabled...

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` and then `pip install insightface==0.7.3
`

Comment: Have you run the script to load your build env variables first, eg `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"` ? (or without x86 if you run Python x64)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Python version. If the version is higher than 10, install Python again, but with an older version, it is recommended to use the Linux operating system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
python --version
```

I need to install Visual C++
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504552/how-to-install-visual-c-build-tools)!

We also need to install onnx. Run the following command in the terminal:

```
pip install onnx
```