How to install C standard headers for Visual Studio build tools?
I installed Visual Studio build tools using winget as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053709/60075.
However, I am trying to compile some C code. I'm getting an error
example.h(13): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

It looks as though the standard C header files haven't been installed. I've searched under all of c:\Program Files\ and c:\Program files (x86)\ (Microsoft directories and elsewhere). I can find a stdint.h and stdbool.h under
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\include\

but I can't find stddef.h, stdlib.h, stdio.h.
What winget command can be used to install the standard C header files?

Those files are part of Windows SDK. In addition to Build Tools you also need to install relevant version of Windows SDK to be able to compile C programs for Windows. To do so using winget on Windows 11 run: winget install -e --id Microsoft.WindowsSDK

"No package found matching input criteria."

@CraigMcQueen are you sure winget is up to date on your side? The package in question is here https://winget.run/pkg/Microsoft/WindowsSDK
